# Stream a MP3 to a media device on a schedule

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, windows-task-scheduler, audio-streaming, broadcast

With a lack of a wired PA system we are utilizing speakers connected to few Linksys RE6700 devices (that we were already using as WiFi extenders) to make audio play in different areas of a building. We simply use Windows 10 Cast to Device feature in order to do so when we need to.

What we want now is to be able to automate so that we could play a specific MP3 file (say the college anthem) at a specific time of the day. I have not found a way to invoke this command so that I could possibly do the automation using Task Scheduler. I'm open to using a lightweight third-party tool to do this also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a streaming app but, I solved this requirement using a Raspberry Pi and Nod-Red (which we were already using).

The RPi was loaded with [RuneAudio](http://www.runeaudio.com/) and a play list of what we wanted to play was loaded via RuneAudio UI. Then using node-red, per the schedule, we'd send out a HTTP Request to http://runeaudio.local/command/?cmd=play and it'll execute the play list.